# ActiveRecord query for related elements

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Solutions model, with `has_many` Reviews, and Reviews with 'has_many' ReviewValues. Each ReviewValue is also linked to a Tag which contains the tag name.
I'm trying to select the avarage `scores` (for all the Tags so grouped by tag) that go with a particular solution.

Basically the Reviews model is the join table between Solutions and ReviewValues (and there's also the Tags table which contains the names)

What I have so far is this:

```
@total = self.reviews.review_values.average(:score)
```

The problem is that I can only call review_values on one specific review and not for all of them. so I'd have to do something like `self.reviews.first.review_values...`which doesn't help me because I need the average for each reviewvalue (by Tag name)

This is what the review_values table looks like:

```
Table review_values
===================
id, tag_id, review_id, score, created_at, updated_at
-------------------
id               int(11) PK
tag_id           int(11)
review_id        int(11)
score            int(11)
created_at       datetime
updated_at       datetime
```

And the tags table:

```
Table tags
==========
id, name
----------
id               int(11) PK
name             varchar(255)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using :through ?
eg:

```
class Solution
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :review_values, :through => :reviews
end

@total = my_solution.review_values.average(:score)
```

Comment: This seems to work. Any idea how I can get the average for each tag_id?

Comment: Good question - is that like a "double through" there? ie review_values have_many tags ?" if so - it might be a bit more complex... I don't think I've ever tried a double-through before. But it might just be worth giving it a go (eg "Solution has_many tags :through :review_values")

Comment: I was able to do it with a join `averages = self.review_values.joins(:tag).group(:tag).average(:score)` thanks for your help!